# cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'interceptors' Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have checked several similar issues but none could solve my problem.
I have added interceptor in my spring xml config file and it is throwing me the above mentioned error.

My xml formation looks like below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
....
...

    <mvc:annotation-driven .. />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        ...
        ...

    </bean>
    <bean id="diffrent id"
        ...
        ...

    </bean>
    <bean id="diffrent id"
        ...
        ...

    </bean>

    // added interceptor below
    <interceptors>
            <mapping path="/*"/>
            <bean class="path of class" ></bean>
    </interceptors>
    <context:component-scan base-package="pacakge path" />
</beans>
```

Can you please help me on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">



<mvc:interceptors>
<mvc:interceptor>
  <mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
  <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
   class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
   <property name="paramName" value="j_lang" />
  </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>

 </mvc:interceptors>
```